# Fashion and Wings

Tags: clothing, winged-humans

I have a race of angel-like winged humanoids, hereafter referred to as Avians. They are essentially humans with hollow bones and a single pair of large, feathered wings attached near their shoulders. I haven't quite worked out the specifics of their anatomy but I will let you know as I figure it out.

I am not looking for how they put on their shirts. I have plenty of resources on that. Rather, I'm looking for clothing and accessories that focuses on the wings. Similar to how we have jewellery and shawls for our chests, necks, and arms.

Comment: You should call them Icthids.

Comment: @RonJohn that does sound cool at the least, but what are the roots of the word?

Comment: Google is your friend.

Comment: Can they fly, or the wings are not for flight? (I mean, like the ostriches: they have wings but they cannot fly). If the wings are used for real flight, that limits a lot the things you can put on them.

Comment: @RonJohn all i'm finding is information on a fish-like symbol and something in turkish related to law, please do explain

Comment: the wings are used for short bursts of flight, though flight isn't necessary to get around due to accessibility laws and whatnot.

Comment: *Icthys* is the (ancient?) Greek word for fish (which is pretty different from avian).

Comment: [Reminder to close-voters](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/q/3773/6986): The problem cannot be fixed if the OP is not made aware of it.

Comment: That being said, I don't see this as a worldbuilding task, rather as a consequence of a character's personal taste. Maybe one individual likes beads while another likes gemstones or special ink.

Comment: I think a lot of the VTCs are because stack exchange isn't designed to get a list of decorative items.  The best decorative items are *highly* individual.  Just look at all the things humans have done to themselves.  If you come up with something you think people haven't done to their bodies, it means you haven't looked hard enough! It might be more effective to ask what properties said decorative items would need to have to minimize their impact on short bursts of winged flight.  Things like aerodynamics, attachments, and inertia would have a large impact on the practicality of these items.

Comment: I've gotta agree with @Frostfyre.  I can stretch this by assuming there are cultural or religious issues that might color how they accesorize their wings, but the reality is it's a personal choice and the personal choices of characters are off-topic.  Frankly, what do we do to our hair?  They'd do the same thing to their wings (so long as it didn't hinder flight).  Dyes come to mind.  Check out the Pierson's Puppeteers in Niven's *Ringworld* books and how they decked out their manes.

Comment: If you haven't already seen it, there's a [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) where people can help you massage the question into a form that will be better accepted.

Comment: Looks like a good worldbuilding question to me. Really: if simple math questions and "real world questions" are on topic, why is it questions about actual *invented worlds* and *constructed cultures* are closed? This should be reopened.

Answer (score 2):

**Clothing Ideas:**

- You could have wing bags that hang at the bottom of the wings while not in flight to collect molting/loose feathers if there is a special significance to one's feathers or on cleanliness.
- Depending on the durability of the wings, the weather of your world, or the value of feathers have a covering/cape to protect them. This could also be used to keep one's wings pristine to show off.

**Jewelry**

- Similar to piercings have a ring that trophies/ornaments could hang off of (I was thinking feathers of friends/family/powerful avians/enemies beaten-because they'd be light enough to still fly). I don't know how realistic a ring piercing is on a wing so this could be something closer to a clip.
- Any comparable jewelry...gold/silver clips/chains to show off wealth and strength because they have to be able to fly with it too.

Answer (score 0):

I would suspect, being angels and all, that the problem would be taken care of by divine biology. Like peacocks, for instance. Natural plumage adornment and coloring. Or the Monarch Butterfly.

No human artificial accouterments could ever compare to mother nature.

Answer (score 0):

**Shirts that button down the sides.**

Picture if you will a shirt sewn together only at the top.  the front looks like a normal shirt, covering the whole chest, the back is shaped more like a formal vest, or even the back of a bathing suit - wide open at the shoulder blades.

The shirt is pulled over the head (perhaps the arms go into sleeves attached on the front. The back drapes over the wings, then it's attached together via buttons, snaps, ties, at each side.